# Render page with theme wrapper from custom controller?

Tags: theming, entities, page-controller

I've created a page layout using panels in the Drupal admin UI (page_machine_id). I'm trying to load that page into a custom controller like so and render one of the variants (Drupal 8):

```
public function profile() {
    $page = \Drupal\page_manager\Entity\Page::load('page_machine_id');
    $variants = $page->getVariants();
    $pageVariant = end($variants);
    $viewer = new \Drupal\page_manager\Entity\PageVariantViewBuilder();
    $pageArray = $viewer->view($pageVariant);
    return new Response(render($pageArray));
}
```

This renders the page content correctly, but does not include the theme wrapper around it and I can't figure out how to get the theme to show.

Thanks.

Comment: Just `return $pageArray;` should be enough

Comment: Thought I tired that but apparently not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

solution is

```
    return $pageArray;
```

Adding Response bypasses Drupals rendering.

Comment: Yes, you can return either a render array or a Symfony Response object.